# Supported search queries with OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What values the `'search-text'` can take in the following query?

```
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

From experiments, it looks like the `{search-text}` is a single string that would be searched in the contents of the file.  Meaning if the search text is a multiple word sentence then entire sentence is searched rather than individual works in the sentence? Is this right assumption?

Eg: Say If I would like to search `'word1' 'word2' ... 'wordn'` then it looks like search query should be issued for all the n words individually.  Is there a format/way in which we can search all the n words in single query?

Thanks,
/Girish BK

Answer (score 3):

[Searching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search) is phrase based and does not support wildcards or similar search augmentations.

For example, the query `/me/drive/search(q='pizza shop')` would search for files that contain the phrase "pizza shop" in a filename, a file's metadata, and a file's content.

Comment: do you know how to do OR or AND searches? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526134/does-microsoft-graphs-search-query-language-for-drive-accept-and-or-or-operat